# How to ensure that sets of pairs are selected with sql which don't exclude each other

Tags: mysql, sql, vba, ms-access

So I have a table with the fields [Map] and [Data] (and other stuff).  The user is able to select inputs that resolve to pairs of data for [Map] and [Data].  Each combination of [Map] and [Data] is unique. I need to construct an sql statement that selects multiple pairs of these unique [Map] and [Data] combinations.

```
Public Function doesHavePriorSetRequirements(n As String) As Boolean
'Add Combination Recognition Here 
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim qr As String, _
    num As String
Dim i As Integer

'Check to see if nomenclature named so far blocks the passed unit
qr = "SELECT * FROM [" & n & "]"
For i = 0 To numOfFeatureElements Step 1
    num = padStringWithToFrontOf("0", CStr(i), Digit2PadPremadeFeats)

    If Not (Form_ReportGenerator.Controls("txtFeat" & num).Value = "" Or _
        IsNull(Form_ReportGenerator.Controls("txtFeat" & num).Value) Or _
         IsEmpty(Form_ReportGenerator.Controls("txtFeat" & num).Value)) Then

        If qr = "SELECT * FROM [" & n & "]" Then
            qr = qr & " WHERE ("
        ElseIf Left(qr, Len("SELECT * FROM [" & n & "] WHERE")) = _
                               "SELECT * FROM [" & n & "] WHERE" Then
            qr = qr & " AND "
        End If
        qr = qr & "([" & n & "].[Data] = """ & _
             Form_ReportGenerator.Controls("txtFeat" _
             & num).Value & """ AND [" & n & "].[Map] = " & _
             getMapFromDesc(Form_ReportGenerator.Controls("lblFeat" & num).Caption) & ")"

    End If
Next i
If Not qr = "SELECT * FROM [" & n & "]" Then
    qr = qr & ")"
End If
qr = qr & ";"
Set rs = localDB.OpenRecordset(qr)

doesHavePriorSetRequirements = Not rs.EOF 
End Function
```

Which will produce a string (qr) such as the following:

```
SELECT * FROM [DV] WHERE (([DV].[Data] = "A" AND [DV].[Map] = 15) 
AND ([DV].[Data] = "3" AND [DV].[Map] = 12));
```

Can someone please confirm for me that the produced string produces a record set that the record set will contain both pairs rather than the pairs excluding each other.  Essentially, does the "AND" between the parenthesis [the and in ") AND ("] include the pairs as both possible records or does it try to chain them all together indifferent of my attempts to pair the two fields and hence look for two values in the same field resulting in no records ever produced?

Comment: You want esentially a record where col1=x AND col1=y.How can you have a col equal two different values at the same time?Use OR in the middle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM [DV] 
WHERE 
([DV].[Data] = "A" AND [DV].[Map] = 15) 
OR 
([DV].[Data] = "3" AND [DV].[Map] = 12)
```